# removing self from a vaiable raise error in python code, why?

Tags: python, kivy

I am practicing few of the kivy tutorial, a peace of code is quite confusing for me i just want an explanation for this so that I can build up strong concepts.

```
from random import random 
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget 
from kivy.uix.button import Button 
from kivy.graphics import Color, Ellipse, Line

class MyPaintWidget(Widget):
    def on_touch_down(self, touch):
        color = (random(), 1,1)
        with self.canvas:
            Color(*color, made='hsv')
            d = 30.
            Ellipse(pos=(touch.x-d/2, touch.y-d/2),size=(d,d))
            touch.ud['line']= Line(points=(touch.x, touch.y))

    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        touch.ud['line'].points += [touch.x, touch.y]

class MyPaintApp(App):
    def build(self):
        parent = Widget()
        self.painter = MyPaintWidget()
        #painter = MyPaintWidget()
        clearbtn = Button(text="Clear")
        clearbtn.bind(on_release=self.clear_canvas)
        parent.add_widget(self.painter)
        #parent.add_widget(painter)

        parent.add_widget(clearbtn)
        return parent

    def clear_canvas(self, obj):
        self.painter.canvas.clear()
if __name__=="__main__":
    MyPaintApp().run()
```

My Question is that, if you look at the code two lines have been commented out when I use these lines as a part of the code, the widget appears and i can draw lines without any problem but when I push the clear button It raise an error.

```
"AttributeError: 'MyPaintApp' object has no attribute 'painter'"
```

While adding the line with self.painter (excluding previous lines) work fine and It clears the Canvas area.

Whay does it show this behavior in the absence of self. Though, I understand the use of self but this time code is quite confusing for me.

Comment: `painter` is local to the _function_, `self.painter` is visible from the object instance...

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Fabre  thanks for you explanation, when I remove self from "self.painter.canvas.clear()" it is raising an error  "NameError: global name 'painter' is not defined" . That means when I am creating an object painter it referring to the current instance of the class MyPaintApp and hence without  self it acts like an orphan variable or object. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python `self` represents current instance. If you assign something to self, it will be added to current object, and can be reused by other methods (in this case: `clear_canvas`).

If you omit `self`, the `painter` variable is a local variable, and will not be added to object. Call to `clear_canvas` will throw exception, because it needs this variable to be accessible.